# calculate the sum of all element in a double array

Tags: c++, recursion

i am a bit confused in using array in doing recursion, can anyone correct my mistake?

new update, based on question required some of the line cannot be edit

```
double sum_of_array(double x[],int size)
{
    static double sum; <---can be edit
    int index = 0; <--can be edit

    if(index<size){
        return sum + sum_of_array(x,size-1); <--can be edit
    } else {
       something ; <--can be edit
       return sum; <--can be edit
    }
}

int main(void){
    double x[] = {4.5,5.0,6.8};
    double y[] = {4.7,3.4,2.5,5.2};

    cout<<"Sum X = "<<sum_of_array(x,3)<<endl;
    cout<<"Sum Y = "<<sum_of_array(y,4)<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

output:

```
Sum of the element in X[]=15.3

Sum of the element in Y[]= 15.8
```

Comment: BTW: `4.5 + 5.0 + 6.8 == 16.3 != 15.3`

Comment: Voting to close as "why not working".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never actually add the values in `x[]` and `y[]` to `sum` and in addition, `index` is always equal to `0`. You should probably pass it as another parameter to the function:

```
double sum_of_array(double x[], int size, int index)
{
    if(index<size){
        return x[index] + sum_of_array(x, size, index+1); 
    }
    else {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

You don't actually need the `sum` variable.

Comment: but note that `index` is always equal to 0.

Comment: i cant get the output that i want with your method ><

Comment: @lowcheemun Why? Are you getting errors or is it outputting incorrectly?

Comment: i am sorry,your method is correct, but then i cannot edit the method line, please refer to new updated, thanks

Answer (score 6):

You're trying to craft something extremely overengineered. You need two things - an edge case (recursion cut-off) and a general case (descend in recursion). In your case the edge case is "array size is zero" and the general case is "grab the first element and pass the rest of array into recursion".

It could be something like this:

```
double sum_of_array( double x[], int size )
{
    if( size == 0 ) { //this is the edge case
        return 0;
    }

    // here you grab the first element and pass the rest of array into a recursive call
    return x[0] + sum_of_array( x + 1, size - 1 );
}
```

Comment: this if statement cannot be change, must be  if(index<size)

Comment: @low chee mun: You don't need `index`.

Comment: You can make this more efficient by using tail recursion: add a third parameter `value`, which you return if `size` is zero, and the last line becomes `return sum_of_array(x + 1, size - 1, value + x[0])`.

Answer (score 2):

There are quite some errors in this code:

- First, the constant sum seems to be useless.  What is ever used for?
- Second, you never take the contents of x in your function.

Comment: i was tried to add x with something like sum_of_array(x,index) but it seem no work

Answer (score 2):

The logic of your recursive function is just wrong.  You never actually read the contents of the array.  I'm surprised you got any meaningful output out of that.

You need to rethink of the recursive definition to perform this addition.

Base case(s):
Sum of an empty array is `0.`.
i.e., `sum_of_array(x, 0) == 0.`

Sum of a 1-element array is the value of the element.
i.e., `sum_of_array(x, 1) == x[0]`

Recursive case:
Sum of an n-element array is the sum of the nth element and the sum of the first `n-1` elements.
i.e., `sum_of_array(x, n) == x[n-1] + sum_of_array(x, n-1)`

Figure out how to encode this logic in your function.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are using a static variable `sum` instead of `x[size - 1]`. Showing how to fix this is redundant at this moment (7 answers already do this). However, this can be done in one line with built in c++ capabilities:

```
#include <algorithm>
double sum_of_array(double x[], int size)
{
    return std::accumulate(x, x + size, 0.);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Error is you did not initialized static variable sum.

Comment: None of your code initialized sum, it depends on which platform and which configuration you are running your code, but generally, your code will get random answers.

Answer (score 0):

I'd start with this:

```
    return sum + sum_of_array(x,size-1);
```

Shouldn't you be returning:

```
    return x[size] + sum_of_array(x,size-1);
```

Besides this, you should find a way to set `sum` to zero between initial calls to the function, because otherwise it will accumulate the sum of *all* the arrays you attempt to sum up.

The point is, you never initialize `sum`, so it has some sort of garbage there.

Whose idea was it to use a *recursion* of all things when a simple `for` loop would do the trick?  Is this homework?

Answer (score 0):

```
double sum_of_array(double x[],int size)
{
    size = size - 1;
    if(size < 0){
        return 0; 
    }
    return x[size] + sum_of_array(x, size);
}
```

Comment: based of question required, i am not suppose to edit if statement,it must be if(index<size)

Answer (score 0):

Ok then it should be like this:

```
double sum_of_array(double x[],int index)
{
    int size = sizeof( x) / sizeof( x[0] );
    if(index<size){
        return x[index] + sum_of_array(x, index + 1);
    }
    return 0;

}
```

then call

```
sum_of_array(x,0);
```

IE you always call the first time with 0 as the index

Comment: Output:
int size shadows a parameter and the sum of x and y both are zero, this is not what i want

Answer (score 0):

Ok last attempt:

```
double sum_of_array(double x[], int index, int size)
{
    if(index < size){
        return x[index] + sum_of_array(x, index + 1, size);
    }
    else {
        return 0;
    }

}
```

then

```
cout<<"Sum X = "<<sum_of_array(x,0,3)<<endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I've done it:

```
double sum_of_array(double x[], int size)
{
    if(size == 0){
        return 0;
    }

    else{
        return x[--size] + sum_of_array(x, size);
   }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope I can still chime in with my answer. The most recent answer excluding mine is from 2011.

This is yet another solution to calculate the sum of all elements in an array.

```
double array_sum(double *p_array, int idx_low, int idx_high){
   if(idx_low == idx_high)
      return p_array[idx_low];
   int idx_mid=idx_low+(idx_high-idx_low)/2;
   return array_sum(p_array,idx_low,idx_mid)+array_sum(idx_mid+1, idx_high);
}
```

Analysis of this algorithm would yeild a run-time of `O(n*log(n))`.
However, you'd do wise to take this statement with a pinch of salt.